# SurfaceView не отрисовывается на Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

У меня есть экземпляр класса Canvas, и SurfaceView на который отрисовывается превью с камеры. Другие Drawable объекты(кнопки например) отрисовываются на Canvas, а SurfaceView нет. Как мне заставить SurfaceView отрисовываться на Canvas, или есть какой способ получить с него Bitmap?

Comment: А что Вы, собственно, хотите получить - снимок экрана или изображение с камеры?

Comment: Я бы хотел изображение с камеры, но не сохраняя его на диск, мне нужно распознавание текста примерно как в приложение гугл переводчик.